# Using "and" instead of ampersand in natbib in-text citations ("\citet")

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I am using `natbib` and a modified `\bibliographystyle` that approximates the APA style (downloaded from here: http://web.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/images/apa-good.bst.zip).

The only problem is this: In APA, when multiple-author citations appear in parentheses, the author names should be connected with "&". However, when multiple-author citations appear outside of parentheses (e.g., at the beginning of a sentence), the author names should be connected with "and". This is something I have not managed to achieve.

I know how to get into the .bst and make the global change from "&" to "and" (i.e., changing the `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}...`). This is not what I need, however.

I was wondering whether anyone has any idea how this problem can be solved (without substituting `natbib` with another package).

Comment: The latest version of `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option is able to solve this problem. It follows the commands of `natbib` so no need for major restructuring in the main document. Unfortunately, the `natbibapa` option currently has a bug that can be solved by following the instructions in this post [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45048/new-apacite-package-2012-feb-14-problem). Anyway, I hope this helps some people with similar problem.

Comment: If this has solved your problem (or almost), then you should write a self-answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Switched the comment of Bonni to an answer</sub>

The latest version of `apacite` with the option `natbibapa` is able to solve this problem. It follows the commands of `natbib` so no need for major restructuring in the main document. Unfortunately, the option `natbibapa` currently has a bug that can be solved by following the instructions in the post [New apacite package (2012-Feb-14) problem?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45048/new-apacite-package-2012-feb-14-problem). Anyway, I hope this helps some people with similar problem.